# How to parse user input while ignoring noise words in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to write a simple text adventure game in C++. I want to allow the user to be able to type in phrases such as "GET THE DOG" where the code would ignore 'THE' and just give me the important things like 'GET' and 'DOG'. I also want the game to support movement, so another example of a phrase could be something like "MOVE TO THE LEFT" where the game would ignore 'TO' and 'THE' and only pay attention to 'MOVE' 'LEFT'.

Anyone have any tips on how to write a function to do this? I thought at first I could use getline, but the only way I think I can get that to work, is if I already know the position of the important words. My friend suggested using substr to put the strings into a vector, then iterating over that. But even that way I'm not too sure how I'd use substr to do such a thing.

Thanks!

```
    char str[100];
    cin.getline(str,100);
    char* point;
    pint = strtok(str, " ");

    while(piont != NULL){
        cout<<point<<endl;
        point = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

here is something I've divvied up while trying to figure out how to do this. I'm not really sure why it works, but its doing something right. Its pointing to full on words, because whenever i print the pointer, its printing the word before the whitespace.

Comment: If you're interested in C++, I would highly recommend picking a different learning exercise because you won't learn as much from this as you think.  If you're interested in text adventures, I'd highly recommend picking a different language.  Perl, Python, Inform (which is specifically designed for text adventures)

Comment: unfortunately, C++ is my only option.

Comment: Well, start here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string  Everything you need to remove words, find words, etc.  But generally parsing human language is stupidly complicated, which makes this question *very* broad, which is why it's getting downvoted.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please take a moment to review our [how-to-ask page](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added an example @SteveFest

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach would be to split the input up into words (probably in a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), and filter ([`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)) the words using a set (probably a [`std:: unordered_set<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)) of ["stop words"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words). Then you can try to make sense of what's left.

Technically, a stop word is a word so common that it is pointless to use it in a search. I don't know why they are called "stop words", but it is definitely the usual term and you can use it to find some common lists. Not all of them are "noise", in your sense, but I think all your noise words will be on common stop word lists.